# How do I redirect Crowdflower users to my website?

Tags: crowdflower

I have a specific problem: I would like to create a Crowdflower job, in which the participant will be redirected to my website (let's say http://www.xxx.yy), where he will complete the task and after he finishes, he'll be redirected back to Crowdflower and paid. Is it possible to do something like that?

I imagined they would have an API, where the user would get some token, which would be then sent to my website and after the completion of the job I could simply do some API call to mark the task as finished. However, I can't find anything in their documentation that would do such thing (http://success.crowdflower.com/customer/portal/articles/1288323).

The reason I need to redirect users to my website is that I need more freedom than CML (Crowdflower Markup Language which is used for creating tasks) offers:

- I need to be able to embed an swf file
- the swf file should be chosen randomly from an aray of files (approx. 10)
- I need to be able to measure how long s/he spends on the website and act based on that time
- store some data into a database

All these things can be done pretty easily using some Javascript and PHP, but i don't think they can be done in CML, that's why I need to redirect them to my website.

Can you, please, give me some advice how to do this?

Comment: have you got this working?! I am trying to do the same and no information available online.

Comment: @m.othamn do you have any success with that?

Comment: I usually don't go here, so missed the comments. I was unable to do it as I wanted, so I asked the participants to visit my link, I implemented all functionality I needed on a separate website and upon completion of the task I showed the user a token which he had to enter into the crowflower task in order to get paid. The situation might be different now, though.